# Ethereum check execution of transaction

Tags: web3js

When executing an ethereum transaction using web3.js how can I be sure that the transaction has been executed successfully? On Rinkeby testnet sometimes I get an error

> Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly send. Be aware that it might still be mined!

If my transaction can still be mined how can I make sure if the transaction is mined or not after getting an error in web3?

Comment: use web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hashString [, callback])

Comment: A not mined transaction often is caused by setting a low gas price. You can override your transaction submitting another transaction with the **same** nonce and a higher gas price. Another possibility is you do not have enough funds to pay for the transaction, and it might be mined when you get more funds.